# What does an asterisk before the CSS background-color mean?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I see this code. Can someone tell me what the * before background-color means and does it matter in a modern browser? Note this is the CSS used in Bootstrap 2.3. Also what is the purpose of background-repeat when used with a gradient? Is this needed?

```
   background-color: #5bb75b;
   *background-color: #51a351;
   background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #62c462, #51a351);
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The *background question:**

```
.classABC {
background: #000; /* modern browsers */
*background: #333; /* IE 7 and below */
 _background: #FFF; /* IE6 exclusively */
}
```

It is used for older IE versions.

**The background-repeat question:**

It has no particular use here.
As you seem to know, it repeats images along the x-axis. Maybe there are pictures applied to the element/child elements where it is needed.